# MySQL returns 2 values for every field requested

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When doing a query() with a select statement the results contain two entries for field.

```
$sql = "select first_name, last_name from users";
$rslt = $conn->query($sql);
```

in the example above, the results would contain 4 items in the array. 2 with incrementing integers for the key, one with a key set to "first_name" and one with the key set to "last_name".

```
Array ( [first_name] => Bill [0] => Bill [last_name] => Johnson [1] => Johnson )
```

I'm sure this is a stupid question, but is there a quick way to either change the way the results are returned so it only contains one key=>value for each field or is there a way to quickly remove the extra data?

What I want for a final array is one of two things...

Required result 1

```
Array ( [first_name] => Bill [last_name] => Johnson )
```

Required result 2

```
Array ( [0] => Bill [1] => Johnson )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$result->fetch_assoc()`.. I guess you're using `_array`.

Comment: @msfoster, that's mysqli, not pdo

Comment: Oh, didn't see the tag. Sorry. The issue is however the same.

Comment: sorry, I should have stated PDO in the message. @msfoster if it's the same issue, how do I accomplish it with PDO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PDO, you can set the fetch mode

```
$rslt = $conn->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

it defaults to returning both types.

See  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php  for more information

Comment: @Doon the manual actual lacks description about using a fetch_style in `query()`.  Edit:  I see it now in the note.  It uses other parameters and passes them as setFetchMode().

Comment: @ThrowBackDewd, if you wan't both numeric and associative arrays, you'd be better off manipulating the PDOStatement object than running query() twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a second parameter to `query()` to change the mode. In your case `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` or `PDO::FETCH_NUM`. I assume the default value is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, which creates both indexes and column names in the result array.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the manual for **[fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)** under **fetch_style**:

> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name as returned
>   in your result set
>
> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column
>   name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set
>
> PDO::FETCH_BOUND: returns TRUE and assigns the values of the columns
>   in your result set to the PHP variables to which they were bound with
>   the PDOStatement::bindColumn() method
>
> PDO::FETCH_CLASS: returns a new instance of the requested class,
>   mapping the columns of the result set to named properties in the
>   class. If fetch_style includes PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE (e.g.
>   PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE) then the name of the class is
>   determined from a value of the first column.
>
> PDO::FETCH_INTO: updates an existing instance of the requested class,
>   mapping the columns of the result set to named properties in the class
>
> PDO::FETCH_LAZY: combines PDO::FETCH_BOTH and PDO::FETCH_OBJ, creating
>   the object variable names as they are accessed
>
> PDO::FETCH_NAMED: returns an array with the same form as
>   PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, except that if there are multiple columns with the
>   same name, the value referred to by that key will be an array of all
>   the values in the row that had that column name
>
> PDO::FETCH_NUM: returns an array indexed by column number as returned
>   in your result set, starting at column 0
>
> PDO::FETCH_OBJ: returns an anonymous object with property names that
>   correspond to the column names returned in your result set

What you want is appropriate fetch style instead of `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` (default) as the first parameter of `fetch()`.

What you want to do is use the **[PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)** object returned by `query()`.

```
$sql = "select first_name, last_name from users";
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
$num = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$assoc = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I believe that will work but I haven't tested if fetchAll can be run twice on the same statement.